# ASP.NET LoginStatus: logout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, membership-provider

I'm working on a web-app using Membership Provider to implement authentication and user/role access to application sections.

I'm using `LoginStatus` control in my master page as logout link, but testing it I discovered that logout doesn't work. If I try to access again to any page of my application (after loggin-out) the page is shown...

I suppose this problem depends on data stored in user session that isn't cleared automatically. That's right?

So which is the corect way to implement logout and clear session?

**NOTE**
I'm not implementing any event for the `LoginStatus` control. I'm using Form authentication. In my login page I'm using this code:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
   1, // Ticket version
   this.txtUser.Text, // Username associated with ticket
   DateTime.Now, // Date/time issued
   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Date/time to expire
   true, // "true" for a persistent user cookie
   ruolo, // User-data, in this case the roles
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
   hash);

if (ticket.IsPersistent) { cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration; }

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

In my **web.config** `system.web` section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" domain="keyforup.it"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: I had something like this before, what i found the problem to be was the `SessionID` kept changing due to an invalid IIS settings, make sure you print out the `SessionID` to the page to make sure that its not changing.

Comment: "If I try to access again to any page of my application (after loggin-out) the page is shown" - do you have anything in web.config to prevent pages being shown to unauthenticated users - e.g. deny users="?" in the system.web/authorization section of web.config

Comment: Why don't you just use `Request.IsAuthenticated`?

Comment: @mattytommo Because then you'd have to add that check for every request that could possibly come in. Using the authorization element lets IIS do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Session.Abandon()` in `LoggedOut` event of `LoginStatus` control solves the issue, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you post your `LogOut` action? Just using `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` is *arguably* cleaner :)

Comment: @mattytommo unfortunately `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 2):

I almost lost my mind trying to find a solution to this problem.  Everything Works fine on other browsers but the firefox and chrome does not log the user out on the initial page after login.

When I set the action property of the form in the site.master file as action="default.aspx" it started to work.

When I looked in the explorer debugger the form action had the default value but on chrome and firefox action had not property set.  I am thinking that this might be a problem with the .net login status controls scripts.

Since my system now Works I wont search further but I hope this will be helpfull to someone having similar problem.